# Tooltip in Gantt Highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I have problems with the Gantt Highcharts tooltip when scrolling.

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykvCp.png)

As you can see in the image, the tooltip is behind the Gantt, I tried this code fragment but it doesn't work:

```
// JS

tooltip: {
    style: {
        zIndex: 9999
    }
},
```

This is my full code: https://jsfiddle.net/carmaro/ygvza0Lm/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to enable the `outside` option for a tooltip. For example:

```
tooltip: {
    outside: true,
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r5jf0v96/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.outside